# video formatting on iOS

Tags: ios, video, video-capture, video-processing, mov

I have just started working on one project where I need to compress and send video to a server from an iOS client device.

While doing some testing on iPhone 4. The native camera app uses .MOV format for video and 1 minute recording is almost 100MB.

This is totally not working for me to send it over wiFi or 3G.

If quality of video is not that important, what option do I have. to get medium quality, low size, longer recording and able to transfer it over the network under resolvable amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AVFoundation framework for recording video and set a suitable session preset, for example `AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium` or `AVCaptureSessionPresetLow` which is suitable for sharing over 3G.